# firebaseui with vuejs typescript and pwa

Tags: typescript, vue.js, firebaseui, progressive-web-apps, vue-cli

I a trying to use firebaseui in a new created project:

I create the project using vue cli 3, i am using PWA and TypeScript
[enter image description here][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYugV.png .

I successfully connect to Firebase and retrieve data from Firestore.

But i cant understand how to use firebaseui (I already used firebaseui in previous simple project without PWA and TypeScript)

When i try to initialize firebaseui i receive the next compilation error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'firebaseui'.
>   'C:/Users/dan/WebstormProjects/travelQuestWebTS/travel-quest/node_modules/firebaseui/dist/npm.js'
>   impl icitly has an 'any' type.

I try to add to tsconfig.json file the noImplicitAny flag

> "noImplicitAny": false,

And that remove the compilation error but now i get a runtime error:

> Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: firebase.initializeApp is not a
>   function"

My initFirebaseui function

```
export const startFirebaseUi = (classId:string) =>{     
// init firebaseui
uiConfig = {
    signInSuccessUrl: '/',
    signInOptions: [
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    ],
}

fireaseUI = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth())

fireaseUI.start(classId, uiConfig)

}
```

Comment: Which version of firebase (not firebaseui) are you using?

Comment: "firebase": "^5.0.2",

Comment: "firebaseui": "^3.0.0",

Comment: There might be some problem with firebase 5.0.2. You should try with firebase version 5.0.1 https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/392